# Why is the list not empty if it initialized as a blank list? (python)

Tags: python

Follow up from this link:
[How do i store the output of the 'count' variable into a list? (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595714/how-do-i-store-the-output-of-the-count-variable-into-a-list-python)

Here is my code:

```
def printTable(items):
    counter_list = []
    for i in  range (len(items[0])):
        print ()
        counter = 0
        for j in range(len(items)):
            if len(items[i][j]) > counter:
                counter = len(items[i][j])
                counter_list.append(counter)
                itemName = items[i][j]
        print ('the longest string is: ' + itemName + '; and its length is ' + str(counter))
        print ('Counter list: ' + str(counter_list))

tableData = [['apples','oranges','cherries','banana'],
             ['Alice','Bob','Carol','David'],
             ['dogs','cats','moose','goose']]


printTable(tableData)
```

The output of this is:

```
the longest string is: cherries; and its length is 8
Counter list: [6, 7, 8]

the longest string is: Alice; and its length is 5
Counter list: [6, 7, 8, 5]

the longest string is: moose; and its length is 5
Counter list: [6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 5]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Inder/Documents/printTable.py", line 19, in <module>
    printTable(tableData)
  File "/Users/Inder/Documents/printTable.py", line 7, in printTable
    if len(items[i][j]) > counter:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You have your indices backwards. It should be `items[j][i]`. Also, I don't get the question. You're appending values to that list; why would you expect it to be empty?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: The first for loop iterates for 4 iterations `(len(items[0])) is 4` but the second for loop iterates for 3 iterations  `len(items) is 3`. Thus there is a index out of bounds error when you try to access the items[3][j] which doesn't exist

Comment: the excepted output: Counter list: [ 8, 5, 5]

Answer (score 0):

You append each item to `counter_list` if it's longer than the previous one.

instead - only append the longest item of the row:

```
def printTable(items):
    counter_list = []
    for i in  range (len(items[0])):
        print ()
        counter = 0
        for j in range(len(items)):
            if len(items[i][j]) > counter:
                counter = len(items[i][j])
                itemName = items[i][j]
        counter_list.append(counter)
        print ('the longest string is: ' + itemName + '; and its length is ' + str(counter))
        print ('Counter list: ' + str(counter_list))
```

Also: instead of `range(len(items))` have a look at [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Actually there is no need to uses item indexes at all though.
Here is slightly refactored version:

```
def printTable(items):
    counter_list = []
    for row in items:
        longest_item, longest_len = '', 0
        for item in row:
            if len(item) > longest_len:
                longest_item, longest_len = item, len(item)
        counter_list.append(longest_len)
        print (f'the longest string is: {longest_item}; and its length is {longest_len}')
        print ('Counter list: ' + str(counter_list))
```

You might also want to have a look at the wonderful [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module:

```
from collections import Counter
def printTable(tableData):
    counter_list = []
    for row in tableData:
        c = Counter({item:len(item) for item in row})
        item, item_len = next(iter(c.most_common()))
        counter_list.append(item_len)
        print(f'the longest string is: {item}; and its length is {item_len}')
        print(f'Counter list: {counter_list}')
```